# Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

Error occurred when I am trying to run `face_rec` using CUDA. There's no file missing, but the system states that it cannot find the related file.

The error is:

```
Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8. 

Error: libcudnn_ops_train.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Please make sure libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8 is in your library path!
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am solving this question. In the NEXT.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.3.0 /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_adv_train.so.8
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.3.0 /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.3.0 /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.3.0 /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.3.0 /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.3.0 /usr/local/cuda-11.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8
```

if your cuda not like me, you should change the cuda-11.5 into your cuda

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! I got the problem solved by changing cuda version